# What is the ruling on working in bank projects?

Tags: halal-haram, riba, work, software, banking

A company is likely interested in hiring me and I am actually going through several interviews. It is a software vendor company that develop products for testing, validating, and virtualizing services. These products are agnostic to any business domain.

In case I am finally hired, I'll be providing consultancy regarding these products to any customer who will acquire a license. It could be retail, transport, telecom customers,...etc.

My question is: Is it permissible for me to accept the job if I am aware that I will likely have to provide consultancy to customers such as banks?

As far as I know, I will not be involved in any riba-involved transactions, nor I am aware of the kind of service they will virtualize.

Answer (score 5):

After reading this [islamqa](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/26771), I have decided to withdraw from the interview process. Today was my last interview but I sent an email this morning to cancel it.

They called me telling me I was the perfect candidate for them and tried to help and understand my reasons which I did not explain in my withdrawal email. After explaining that as a Muslim, I cannot not participate in banking projects because I would be helping and benefiting bank customers in sin and transgression (usury), they tried to convince me to see the positive side of the situation by telling me that I will be working for them and not for the bank, and that I would not be involved in riba-transactions since I would be providing IT consulting services. But seeing I didn't change my mind, they tried to scare me by telling me I was unemployed and that I have to feed my family in these hard times...

Elhamdulilah, I kept polite and firm, and explained again I would not benefit their business if I accept the offer because I would feel guilty and remorse by disobeying Allah's commands. Last but not least, they asked me if could recommend someone I knew for this position. I told them I will think about it, but I won't do it because I would be still sinful recommending someone that will end up helping the banks.

I firmly believe Allah will give me something much better soon :)

Comment: Governments borrow money from World Bank or other countries, which is definitely interest based, to run various projects e.g. health, education, welfare, highways, etc.  Governments keep their money in Central Banks, which lend money to other banks or states or any other financial institutions and earns interest on that money. One of the source of income is Tax payed by citizens. And, there are many such cases.
What about living in such a country? What would be the state of services provided by those borrowing institutions? Should citizens pay taxes or not?

Comment: Governments dealing with usury is beyond the capacity of an individual. Allah does not charge a soul except [with that within] its capacity. http://quran.com/2/286